# Variable indexes outside of defined range in AMPL

Tags: variables, indexing, set, linear-programming, ampl

Not too familiar with AMPL, but running into some issues with indexes...

Basically, I have some variables defined as such:

```
var array{i in set};
```

And I need to do some amount of checking the elements around a given `i` in some of the constraints:

```
subject to Constraint{i in set}:
    array[i] + array[i-1] + array[i+1] <= 12;
```

But obviously `array[0]` or `array[card(set) + 1]` don't exist. To add a further issue, I'm trying to model a sort of problem in which `array[0]` or `array[card(set) + 1]` just shouldn't be factored into our computation at all (e.g. it shouldn't constrain the other variables). Any help appreciated :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AMPL, you can create or define your own "sets" for valid indices and use them in your constraints.

So, in your case, to avoid invalid indices, you can define a set of permissible indices: `param inner_i {2..(N-1)}` and loop over those when creating the constraints.

The price we pay is that we have to explicitly take care of the corner cases.

Here's one way to do it: (Note, I don't have AMPL loaded, so the code is untested.)

```
param N > 0;      #number of elements

set ELEM;         # Elements    
set inner_i {2..(N-1)} > 0; #valid indices

var array {ELEM} >= 0;

subject to LimitSum{i in inner_i}:
    array[i-1] + array[i] + array[i+1] <= 12;

#Take care of the boundary conditions explicitly, if needed
subject to LimitSum_start:
    array[1] + array[2] <= 12;
    #only two elements since array[0] doesn't exist.

subject to LimitSum_last:
    array[N-1] + array[N] <= 12;
    #only two elements since array[N+1] doesn't exist.
```

Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: inner_i should be a set rather than a param: `set inner_i = 2..N-1;`

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that. I updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if-then-else expression to conditionally include some terms:

```
subject to Constraint{i in set}:
    array[i] + (if i != 0 then array[i-1]) + (if i != N then array[i+1]) <= 12;
```

where `N` is the last element of the set.